# Why does my JMS client not consume messages from the Topic?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have ActiveMQ running on the localhost using the default port, 61616. I put some messages in a Topic called `topic.STUDENTS`. I have a client program that I am trying to use to read the messages in the Topic. Here is the main part of the program that does not work as expected. I was expecting to get some of the message back but instead I just receive `null`.

```
 public void receiveMessages() throws URISyntaxException, JMSException, Exception {

    try { 
    //Create a ConnectionFactory 
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

    //Create a Connection
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    //Create a session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    //Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
    Destination destination = session.createTopic("topic.STUDENTS");

    //Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

    //Wait for a message
    Message message = consumer.receive(1000);

    if (message instanceof TextMessage) { 
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
        String text = textMessage.getText();
        System.out.println("Received: " + text);

    } else { 
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);
    }

    consumer.close();
    session.close();
    connection.close();

       } catch(Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Caught: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

This code basically apes the code from ActiveMQ 'Hello World' example: http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html

Does anyone know why I do not receive any messages from the Topic? Here is one message that is in the Topic that I can see through the `./activemq browse topic.STUDENTS` command:

```
JMS_BODY_FIELD:JMSText = Invention-my-dear-friends-is-93%-perspiration-6%-electricity
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSExpiration = 0
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSMessageID = ID:user-thinkpad-335i-59919-1457977678059-1:1:1:1:3
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSPriority = 4
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSDestination = topic.STUDENTS
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSTimestamp = 1457977678409
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSRedelivered = false
JMS_HEADER_FIELD:JMSDeliveryMode = persistent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Topics do not retain messages by default, so if you start the consumer after you've produced the messages then any message that was sent before the consumer arrived is gone.  If you want to consume messages that were produced while your consumer was offline then you need to use a Queue or register a durable Topic subscriber on the Topic prior to producing the messages.

Comment: I think you are probably correct on this. I changed the call on the session reference when creating the `Destination` to `createQueue` and I receive messages as I was expecting. :D This works.